# Trying to delete a file with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

My script is not working.

"sb-pdfs/" is the path where the file is located that I want to delete. If I substitute the $_GET part with the correct file name and call the php scripts directly, then the file is in fact deleted, but not when I try to do it with the Ajax function. I could also just substitute the php with a simple echo which is not called either.

```
<?php 

unlink ('sb-pdfs/'+($_GET['file']));
   
?>
```

So the error seems to be on the AJAX side:

```
  function loeschen(clicked_id)
  {
      alert(clicked_id);
        
      $.ajax({
          url: 'unlink.php',
          data: {'file' : clicked_id },
          success: function (response) {
             if( response.status === true ) {
                 alert('File Deleted!');
             }
             else alert('Did not work!');
          }
        });

    }
```

I get the correct clicked_id alert, but also the "Did not work!" alert and the file is not deleted.

Edit: clicked_id is the filename of the file I want to delete.

Comment: Quite obviously because `response.status` is not equal to `true`; it's probably equal to `"true"`. Try logging it?

Comment: You should not do something like delete a file on your server with a GET request.

Comment: @JeremyThille Ok. And why is that or what do I need to do to make it true?

Comment: I don't know, you wrote your PHP code, so you know what it returns. We don't :)

Comment: @Pointy It is not a public site, the site will be accessible only by one person.

Comment: @JeremyThille I do not even know what the response.status is for; I just want to delete a file on the server.

Comment: I'm not sure what you send as "clicked_id", is it a filename ? is it some kind of other identifier ?

Comment: @Victorbvn Yes, clicked_id is a filename

Comment: `response` is what your PHP file sends back. Apparently it's not returning anything, so `response===""` or maybe `response===undefined` (I haven't touched PHP in ages so I'm not sure). Anyway what I'm sure of is that `response.status` is undefined. It can't be `true`, therefore you always get `'Did not work!'`.

Answer (score 2):

Your string concatenation is incorrect, you need to use dots `.` in PHP

```
unlink ('sb-pdfs/' . ($_GET['file']));
   
?>
```

As other users have pointed it out, it would be a big security issue as it stands, I would advise a lot of parsing or using an ID system instead of filenames